Neovim inlay hints not working for user written functions
I recently moved from Vscode to Neovim maybe a month ago and the one thing that has been bothering me is the lack of inlay hints on my files. Looking for something like this. It works for the vim api functions in my config files, but when I write my own code and functions, they are only recognized as text and therefore the hints don't work. Vim Api Functions My functions
I have made sure I am on Neovim V0.10.0, and have the following in my plugins init.lua:
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    event = "User FilePost",
    opts = { inlay_hints = { enabled = true }, },    config = function()
      require "plugins.configs.lspconfig"
    end,

I also tried adding this to my M.on_attach(client, bufnr):
if client.server_capabilities.inlayHintProvider then
      vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(true, bufnr)
    end

